# Wine application launch error

Tags: linux, debian, wine

I currently have a debian VPS (without UI). I installed wine without worries and during the launch I have an error:

```
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
```

I found a DISPLAY solution but I do not understand it. I tested `echo $ DISPLAY`, this does not send me anything.

Comment: Désolé, mais ceci est un forum anglophone. Comprenez-vous l'anglais? J'ai pris la liberté de traduire votre question.

Comment: Why the need to run Wine in a VPS? I have found customers installing Wine for running the Windows version of teamviewer when there is a native binary for Linux...

Comment: Rui, yes sorry its my bad.

Comment: And i need for execute a .exe on linux...

Comment: is it a common or proprietary application? Is is text or graphical in nature?

Comment: that's an emulator, so graphical, open a window like a terminal